# Binning using original dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
     % Beat EPS  % Beat Rev  % Since
0         0.080     -0.0429     0.280
1         0.000      0.0304     0.012
2         6.667      0.0054     0.388
3        -0.176      0.3277     0.010
4        -0.070     -0.0621     0.059
5         0.182      0.1039     0.234
6         0.625      0.0338    -0.042
7         0.000     -0.0507     0.000
8         0.042      0.0223     0.028
9         0.357     -0.0486    -0.020
```

It continues. I would like to be able to bin all of the columns independently of each other. So for example, if we wanted to use 5 bins, then columns 1,2 and 3 would only be ints 1-5, based on each columns Min and Max independently.

I can probably just hack through this using some for loops, but would like to do it by selecting or indexing the data, and then setting. I am just getting stuck on "setting with chained indexing" and setting with iloc/loc/ix.

I would like to do `df[df['% Beat EPS']<percentile[0]] = 1`, but I know this selection results in a copy being set. I can't figure out how to represent this using iloc,loc and ix. I would like three new columns added to this original dataframe. Thanks!

Edit: Heres how I did it in numpy. But this still modifies the original and does not add it as a column.

```
x = df.values

for i in range(len(x[0])):
    bins = np.percentile(x[:,i],[20,40,50,60,80])
    x[:,i] = np.digitize(x[:,i],bins,right=True)

print x
```

Output example:

```
     % Beat EPS  % Beat Rev  % Since
0             1           0        2
1             1           2        1
2             2           1        2
3             0           2        1
4             0           0        2
5             2           2        2
6             2           2        0
7             1           0        1
8             1           1        1
9             2           0        1
```

Using `bins = np.percentile(x[:,i],[30,65])`

Comment: In other words, you want to scale each column from `[min, max]` range to `[0, bins]` range. and all numbers in `[0, bins]` scale are integers?

Comment: I added output that might help. The example produces three bins, each representing a percentile group of the given column.

Comment: You may want to re-check the output and line following, it quite doesn't match and still not clear what you're trying to establish here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want to do:

```
>>> n = 5  # nbins
>>> np.round(x.rank(pct=True)*(n-1))
```

It ranks the items by their percentage in each column (from 0.0 to 1.0), then scales it to go from 0 to one less than the number of bins, then rounds.